# Div background is not painting the whole Div

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have the following code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/yv983q28xx

**Source:**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing on IE 11</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #d6ffbb;
}
.page-container {
  padding: 10px;
}
footer {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/hYXDL2N/pattern-dark.jpg") top center
    repeat;
}
/* BEGIN OF CODE BLOCK FOR STICKY FOOTER */
body {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.page-container {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
/* END OF CODE BLOCK FOR STICKY FOOTER */
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page-container">
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
    hello world<br />
  </div>
  <footer>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
      since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
      scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
      centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
      essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
      of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
      typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
      text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
      and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
      five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
      essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
      of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
      typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
      text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
      and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
      five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
      essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
      of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
      typesetting industry.
    </p>
    <p>
      Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
      industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
      since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
      scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
      centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
      essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
      of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and
      typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
      text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
      and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
      five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
      essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
      of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
      with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
      of Lorem Ipsum.
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**Demo:** https://yv983q28xx.codesandbox.io/

This code is working fine on: { `Chrome`, `Firefox`, `Edge` }.

But when running on `IE11` I get the following behaviour:

**Scrolled to top**:
[image: scrolled to top]

**Scrolled to bottom** (painting just until the end of previous image):
[image: scrolled to bottom]

As you can see the div background is not painting the whole div when scrolled to bottom.

**Important:** this is a `sticky-footer` implementation, so it is a requirement that when you zoom out the footer get sticked to the bottom of the `screen / viewport`.

Any idea on how to solve this on `IE11` without affecting the other browsers?

If possible, please, fork the `codesandbox.io` and paste the link with your solution here.

Thanks!

Comment: Just looking at the picture and the code, it seems that it may have to do with the fact that you have the body height set to 100%. Do you need that in this case?

Comment: Yes I do. If I remove: `height: 100%;` for the body, then when you zoom out the footer won't be sticked to the bottom of the window / viewport.

Comment: the problem is with IE and flexbox. If you really want to have IE11 compatibility ( don't really know why ) then you should find alternatives to flexbox. This is only one of the many bugs that can appear on IE11 when using flexbox.  Read more here https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox and maybe you can find your solution here https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `flex: 0 0 auto;` to your footer.

[image]